# material ui theme palette does not apply the primary color to the primary button background color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to set the primary color which is the ****background** color** for all material ui controls

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#00629A'
    },
  },
});

 <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <Button>Import</Button>
 </ThemeProvider>
```

What happens is that the button background is always transparent and the **text color** is getting the main value applied!?

What do I wrong?

[image]

When I check that Site: https://zenoo.github.io/mui-theme-creator/#Buttons
and I change the primary color it affects all controls background color!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/#basic-button):

> Basic button
>
> The Button comes with three variants: text (default), contained, and
> outlined.

> Text button
>
> Text buttons are typically used for less-pronounced
> actions, including those located: in dialogs, in cards. In cards, text
> buttons help maintain an emphasis on card content.

> Contained button
>
> Contained buttons are high-emphasis, distinguished by
> their use of elevation and fill. They contain actions that are primary
> to your app.

So your code is working as expected.

If you need to change background color to primary color, you should set `variant` to `contained` like this.

```
<Button variant="contained">Import</Button>
```

If you need to change all buttons, you can use `components` prop.

For example:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#00629A"
    }
  },
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      defaultProps: {
        variant: "contained"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

You can see the whole example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-brook-8w8y4t?file=/Demo.js).

Comment: that works for a single button... thx but I do not want to repeat this for every button.   This code does not work: components: {
        MuiButton: {
          styleOverrides: {
            root: () => ({
              variant: 'contained'
            }),
          },
        },
      }

Comment: components: {
        MuiButton: {
          defaultProps: {
            variant: "contained"
          },
        },
      },

Comment: @HelloWorld, Oops, I updated my answer but it seems that you've already solved the problem.